# Jquery button conditional on graph answer

Tags: jquery, button, graph

I run an online experiment. One of the questions involves drawing a relationship on a graph by dragging and dropping five data points. I record the values where they have 'dropped' the data point (see function UpdatedSeries at end of the code).

I need to add in a check that they are making a conscious effort, i.e. at least 4 out of 5 data points need to be changed from their original position (a straight line at y-axis value 25), before they can click on the 'submit' button. If they click it without having dragged four out of five points, I need to provide a message.

I have however, no idea how to formulate the condition for the button and insert this in the code. It's been a year since I've been working on this code and I seem to be out of practice..

```
function Relation()
{
    $("#chart1").dialog(
    {
        title: "Relationship",
        modal:true,
        resizable:false,
                height: 600,
                width:940,
        show: "fade", 
        hide: "explode",
    buttons: 
        [
            {text: "submit", click: function()
                {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    Completion();
                }}
        ]   
    });

        $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;

  s1 = [[2,25],[50,25],[100,25],[150,25],[200,25],[250,25]];

  plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1',[s1],{
     title: 'Please draw the relationship between the promotional expenditure and rise in sales you inferred from the graphs by dragging and dropping the data points. Change at least 4 data points from their original position.',
    series: [
    {
        label: 'Relation',
        dragable: {
            constrainTo: 'y'
        },
        isDragable: true
    }
],
        axes: {
         xaxis: {

          label:'Promotional expenditure',
          tickInterval:50, 
          min:0, 
          max:300
         },
         yaxis: {

          label:'Sales increase (percentage)' ,
          tickInterval: 10,
          min:0,
          max:60
         }
     },

     cursor: {
         show: true
     }
  });
// add our hook, to fire after a series update
  $.jqplot.postDrawSeriesHooks.push(updatedSeries);

  function updatedSeries() {
    console.log(plot1.series[0].data); //data for the series is here
    var dragArray = plot1.series[0].data;
    $.getJSON("savedrag.php", {dragArray:dragArray});
  }
}
```